# fudge meaning in "What the fudge is going on?!"

Tags: meaning, usage

I came across a sentence in the book **Project Hail Mary**:

> What the fudge is going on?!

I think Irrelevant word ***fudge*** was used instead of ***fuck*** to decrease the rudeness of the sentence (when we are in formal place or in front of our kids).
Did I get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've got it right. This is known as a **[minced oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath)**, and there are lots of similarly innocuous replacements for other impolite expressions or curse words.